# node express mongo API updating a record issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ecmascript-6

i am creating a rest api using node, express, mongoDB. try to make fetch, create, delete , and update functions . all working except update function. when I try to check using postman the code hangs and server stops and errors showing, again when I save the source code the server runs as normal. but every time I try to do the update post the code hangs and error shows up I think something wrong with my update post code, I am beginner in Nodejs , so I am not sure why this error occurs, if anyone knows please check

my crud code is below

```
import express from "express";
import Post from "../models/PostModel.js";

const router = express.Router();

//  get all posts
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const posts = await Post.find();
    res.json(posts);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});

// submits a post
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const post = new Post({
    title: req.body.title,
    message: req.body.message,
  });
  try {
    const savedPost = await post.save();
    res.json(savedPost);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});

// get specific post
router.get("/:postId", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.postId);
    res.json(post);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});

// delete a specific post
router.delete("/:postId", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const removePost = await Post.remove({ _id: req.params.postId });
    res.json(removePost);
  } catch (error) {
    res.json({ message: error });
  }
});

//update a post

router.patch("/:postId", async (res, req) => {
  try {
    const updatedPost = await Post.updateOne(
      { _id: req.params.postId },
      { $set: { title: req.body.title } }
    );
    res.json(updatedPost);
  } catch (error) {
    res.json({ message: error });
  }
});

export default router;
```

this is the error shows up in postman
[image]

---

this is the error shows up in vscode once I try to send the patch request  in postman

[image]

this is the output of get request in postman
[image]

Comment: are there any errors in the console? What is the output of the updatePost variable ? (console.log it), have you tried doing return res.json in place of res.json ?

Comment: @YashKumarVerma sorry just now updated the error images

Comment: you should `return res.json`

Comment: can you share the codebase on some repo ?

Comment: @MukeshSuthar No, `return` is not necessary

Comment: @YashKumarVerma im uploading please wait

Comment: In your patch handler, you flipped the parameter names: `async (res, req) => {` should be `async (req, res) => {` (like everywhere else). You were trying to call `.json()` on what is actually the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you have swapped the location of `req` and `res` in the `.patch` request.

Replace the last section of code with the following code.
**Note it is `req, res` and not `res, req`**

```js
router.patch("/:postId", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const updatedPost = await Post.updateOne(
      { _id: req.params.postId },
      { $set: { title: req.body.title } }
    );
    res.json(updatedPost);
  } catch (error) {
    res.json({ message: error });
  }
});
```

Comment: Just vote to close as a typo

Comment: I do not think that is a typo in the code, rather the OP is confused and not clear what happens when we swap the position of function params

Comment: "*all working except update function*" makes it clear that they did not swap them on purpose, and don't know *what* is wrong with the code

Comment: @YashKumarVerma hi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67921831/react-redux-toolkit-fetching-data-when-refresh-the-page-the-state-gone I have another question posted check can check if possible ?