# react/redux toolkit fetching data - when refresh the page the state gone

Tags: reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am creating a react/redux toolkit app , I am saving data into redux , this is like a posts page and when user clicks a post it goes to single post page,

the data is saving in redux state and working fine, but when I refresh the detail page the redux data is gone not sure why its happening I want to keep data even if user refresh the page also.

my posts slice

```
import {
  createSlice,
  // createSelector,
  // PayloadAction,
  createAsyncThunk,
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";



export const fetchAllPostsAsync = createAsyncThunk(
  "posts/fetchAllPostsAsync",
  async (_, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/posts/");
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      throw thunkAPI.rejectWithValue({ error: error.message });
    }
  }
);

export const postsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "posts",
  initialState: {
    allposts: [],
    loading: "idle",
    error: "",
    selectedPost: {},
  },

  reducers: {
    selectedpost: (state, action) => {
      state.selectedPost = action.payload;
    },
  },

  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchAllPostsAsync.pending, (state, action) => {
      state.allposts = [];
      state.loading = "Loading";
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchAllPostsAsync.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.allposts = action.payload;
      state.loading = "loaded";
    });

    builder.addCase(fetchAllPostsAsync.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.allposts = "data not loaded";
      state.loading = "error";
      state.error = action.error.message;
    });
  },
});



export const { selectedpost } = postsSlice.actions;
export default postsSlice.reducer;
```

my posts page

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import SinglePost from "./SinglePost";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { fetchAllPostsAsync } from "../features/posts/postsSlice";

const Posts = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts.allposts);

  console.log(posts);
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchAllPostsAsync());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button>Add new </button>
      {posts?.map(({ _id, ...rest }) => (
        <SinglePost key={_id} rest={rest} id={_id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Posts;
```

my details page

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { selectedpost } from "../features/posts/postsSlice";
const Details = () => {
  const { postId } = useParams();
 
  const [postshere, setPostshere] = useState(selectedpost);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts.allposts);
  const selectedpostsingle = useSelector((state) => state.posts.selectedPost);
  const selectedPostArray = posts?.filter((post) => post._id === postId);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(selectedpost(setPostshere(selectedPostArray[0])));
  }, [dispatch]);
  console.log(postId, "ffffff");
  return (
    <div>
      <div key={postshere._id}>
        {postshere.title} {postshere.message}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Details;
```

this is single post page

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
const SinglePost = ({ rest, id }) => {
  // let history = useHistory();
  // function handleClick() {
  //   history.push(`/${rest._id}`);
  // }
  console.log(rest);
  return (
    <Link to={`/details/${id}`}>
      <div className="post">
        <div className="post__title">{rest.title}</div>
        <div className="post__body">{rest.message}</div>
        <div className="post__body">{rest.date}</div>
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default SinglePost;
```

error message

```
×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
Details
src/components/Details.js:20
  17 | console.log(postId, "ffffff");
  18 | return (
  19 |   <div>
> 20 |     <div key={postshere._id}>
     | ^  21 |       {postshere.title} {postshere.message}
  22 |     </div>
  23 |   </div>
View compiled
```

Comment: Redux-store data will be reset to its initial state when you refresh the page in the browser. If you want data to persist, you will have to store it in Local Storage. But, in most cases, you don't need to do this. Instead, you need to write code in a way such that it fetches data again from the backend.